# Entity framework caching in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have a MVC.NET application (.NET Framework 4.7.2) which is using MySQL.Data 6.10.7, Entity Framework 6.4.0 and MySQL.Data.Entity 6.10.7.

I also have a MySQL 5.6 database where IoT devices are sending data.

The application is running smoothly on IIS Express while debugging from Visual Studio 2019. It is also running ok when I publish it on local IIS server 10 of my Windows 10. The problems starts when I publish the application to Azure.

Some queries are fetching cached data. New entries at the database are not fetched. After some time (~2hours) those data are also fetched.
I have tried various things found in forums in order to disable Entity framework caching but nothing helped. 
I am pretty sure that it is a caching issue since same Entity requests (logged) from different servers (local, Azure) are fetching different data. The same request from all servers (local, Azure) are fetching the correct data after some time.

Does Azure have a specific setting for Entity framework caching (or caching in general) that I can disable?

Any other idea?

Comment: Are you using the same, shared instance of the database context for multiple queries?

Comment: What do you mean cashed data? Do you mean _cached data_?

Comment: no, I am making a new instance each time.

Comment: Have you done any sql analysis on the databases to see what calls are being made and what's being returned ?

Comment: Please try to [configure server parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-server-parameters). Check if there is some caching enabled there.

Comment: I have set WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION to Never but still nothing

Comment: what do you mean by Entity framework caching....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to completely ignore EF6's cache for data retrieval, then add AsNoTracking() to the end of your query  which is before calling ToList() or doing anything else that would execute the query.

The “**`System.Data.Entity`**” namespace contains this extension and it is very easy to use in our applications. The following is an example of how to use the **`AsNoTracking`** method.

```
using(Entities context = new Entities())  
{  
    var employee = context.Employees.AsNoTracking().ToList();  
    var employee2 = context.Employees  
                    .Where(p => p.EmployeeId >= 3)  
                    .AsNoTracking().ToList();  
}
```

You can read below doc for detailed explanation:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-and-asnotracking/

Additionally , you could try to refresh your DB context if you need fresh data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes i know, AsNoTracking() extension method returns a new query and the returned entities will not be cached by the context (DbContext or Object Context). or alternatively , we can just refresh the DB context if required...

Comment: Your wording implies that you don't quite understand the difference. `tracking and caching are two different things` the way EF tracks is by hold the values... if it doesn't it wouldn't be tacking anything.Whether you use AsNoTracking or not the entities will still be loaded. Using the word cache here just seem plan wrong as its part of the framework.The framework is not a caching framework... so don't try and use it like one. Wording implied as "cache" what is the lifespan, the life span of dbconext, how would this diff from just using just plan garbage collection, from a caching prospective.

Comment: just saying although EF is caching, you should not be using this as an Application "cache" if you intend to cache longer than the lifespan of dbcontext. So referring to the frameworks build it "caching*" which is part of the usage of how the framework works, as cache.... in a wider way... makes it hard to understand. what you mean by EF cache. cache... usually have longer lifespans.. so it confusing as to why you would try use a internal EF cache for anything that has a lifespan which exceeds the UOW(unit of work).

Comment: Correction...maybe you do understand, im just trying to point out that to @raven just in case, he maybe be consuming the EF in a non indented way.

Comment: I have marked your post as the answer since it will help others with caching problems. However, it did not help with my problem. I did use AsNoTracking and I did dispose my DB content and the problem was consisting. Finally I figure out that it was not a caching problem. The hourly delay of data display was due to a bad request containing server datetime instead of local datetime. Thank you all for your time and effort.